# How to find the Choi state of a bipartite quantum channel?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-operation

The Choi state of a quantum channel $\mathcal{N}_A$ acting on a system $\rho_A \in \mathcal{H}^A$ is given by:

$Choi(\mathcal{N}_A) =(
 \mathcal{I}_{A'} \otimes \mathcal{N}_A)|\Phi^+\rangle \langle\Phi^+|_{A'A} \tag{1}$

Where $\mathcal{I}_{A'}$ is the identity operator $\in \mathcal{H}^{A'} \ \text{and} \  dim(\mathcal{H}^{A'}) = dim(\mathcal{H}^{A} ) = d$

$|\Phi^+\rangle$ is unnormalised maximally entangled state $\in \mathcal{H}^{A'} \otimes \mathcal{H}^{A}$ given by
$|\Phi^+\rangle = \sum_{i = 0}^ {d-1} |i\rangle_{A'}|i\rangle_{A}$ where $|i\rangle_{A'} \tag{2} \ \text{and} \  |i\rangle_{A}$ are orthonormal bases in $\mathcal{H}^{A'} \ \text{and} \ \mathcal{H}^{A}$ respectively.

I have a quantum channel $\mathcal{E_{AB}}$ acting on a bipartite state $\rho_{AB} \in \mathcal{H}^A \otimes \mathcal{H}^B$. I want to find the Choi state of this channel.

I have relabelled the bases of $\mathcal{H}^A \otimes \mathcal{H}^B$ so that now it's $\mathcal{H}^{d_A X d_B} =\mathcal{H}^C$. Now the channel can be viewed as a single partite channel on $\mathcal{H}^C$ Now I have done this $(\mathcal{I \otimes \mathcal{E}_C})|\Phi^+\rangle \langle \Phi^+|_{C'C}$ Where $|\Phi^+\rangle_{C'C}$ is the maximally entangled unnormalised state in $\mathcal{H}^{C'} \otimes \mathcal{H}^C$. Is that correct?

Or do I need to form two pairs of maximally entangled states of two qubits $|\Phi^+ \rangle \langle \Phi ^+|_{A'A} \ \text{and} \ |\Phi^+ \rangle \langle \Phi ^+|_{BB'} $ and act the channel on their tensorproduct as $(\mathcal{I}_A' \otimes \mathcal{E}_{AB} \otimes \mathcal{I}_B') (|\Phi^+ \rangle \langle \Phi ^+|_{A'A} \otimes|\Phi^+ \rangle \langle \Phi ^+|_{BB'})$?

Comment: The two approaches should be equivalent: $|\Phi^+\rangle_{AA'}|\Phi^+\rangle_{BB'}=|\Phi^+\rangle_{CC'}$.